# Translate text without using hooks React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am very new to React Native and still in exploring phase but I am using it for my school project. How do I translate my array of prediction using react-native-translator package? Theres only examples by using Hooks but Im using class component. This is how I get my array of prediction output:

```js
<View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? '' : 'Predicting...'}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>
```

Now I want to do translation below it. Something like this:

```js
<View>
      <Translator
        from="en"
        to="ms"
        value={isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        onTranslated={}
      />
      <Text>{result}</Text>
    </View>
  );
```

But I am not sure how should I do it with class component. I really hope someone can give me an idea how to do it.
This is my full code:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        isTfReady: false,
        isModelReady: false,
        predictions: null,
        image: null
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
        await tf.ready()
        this.setState({
          isTfReady: true
        })
        this.model = await mobilenet.load()
        this.setState({ isModelReady: true })
    
        //Output in Expo console
        console.log(this.state.isTfReady)
        this.getPermissionAsync()
      }

      getPermissionAsync = async () => {
        if (Constants.platform.ios) {
          const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
          if (status !== 'granted') {
            alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!')
          }
        }
      }

      imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
        const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true
        const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY)
        // Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
        const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3)
        let offset = 0 // offset into original data
        for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
          buffer[i] = data[offset]
          buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1]
          buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2]
    
          offset += 4
        }
    
        return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3])
      }

      classifyImage = async () => {
        try {
          const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.state.image)
          const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true })
          const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer()
          const imageTensor = this.imageToTensor(rawImageData)
          const predictions = await this.model.classify(imageTensor)
          this.setState({ predictions })
          console.log(predictions)
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }

      selectImage = async () => {
        try {
          let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3]
          })
      
          if (!response.canceled) {
            const source = { uri: response.uri }
            this.setState({ image: source })
            this.classifyImage()
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      }
      renderPrediction = prediction => {
        return (
          <Text key={prediction.className} style={styles.text}> {prediction.className} </Text> 
          )
      }

      translateTo() {
        const [value, setValue] = useState('renderPrediction');
        const [result, setResult] = useState('');

        return (
          <View>
            <Translator
              from="en"
              to="fr"
              value={value}
              onTranslated={(t) => setResult(t)}
            />
            <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={(t) => setValue(t)} />
            <Text>{result}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      
      }
      // naviScreen = () => {
      //   const navigation = useNavigation();
      //   navigation.navigate('ScanScreen');
      // }
    
      render() {
        const { isTfReady, isModelReady, predictions, image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle='light-content' />
        
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
          
          <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
              {(isTfReady && isModelReady) ? (
                 <Text style={styles.text}> APP IS READY FOR SCANNING! </Text>) : <ActivityIndicator size='small' />}
          </View>
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.imageWrapper}
          onPress={isModelReady ? this.selectImage : undefined}>
          {image && <Image source={image} style={styles.imageContainer} />}

          {isModelReady && !image && (
            <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? '' : 'Predicting...'}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map(p => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <Button style={styles.text} title='SAVE THIS IMAGE' ></Button>
        </View>

        <Button title='LIVE Scan Now' onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ScanScreen')}></Button>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored translation code for class-based component:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isTfReady: false,
    isModelReady: false,
    predictions: null,
    image: null,
    textToTranslate: "",
    translationResult: "",
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await tf.ready();
    this.setState({
      isTfReady: true,
    });
    this.model = await mobilenet.load();
    this.setState({ isModelReady: true });

    //Output in Expo console
    console.log(this.state.isTfReady);
    this.getPermissionAsync();
  }

  getPermissionAsync = async () => {
    if (Constants.platform.ios) {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
      if (status !== "granted") {
        alert("Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!");
      }
    }
  };

  imageToTensor(rawImageData) {
    const TO_UINT8ARRAY = true;
    const { width, height, data } = jpeg.decode(rawImageData, TO_UINT8ARRAY);
    // Drop the alpha channel info for mobilenet
    const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height * 3);
    let offset = 0; // offset into original data
    for (let i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 3) {
      buffer[i] = data[offset];
      buffer[i + 1] = data[offset + 1];
      buffer[i + 2] = data[offset + 2];

      offset += 4;
    }

    return tf.tensor3d(buffer, [height, width, 3]);
  }

  classifyImage = async () => {
    try {
      const imageAssetPath = Image.resolveAssetSource(this.state.image);
      const response = await fetch(imageAssetPath.uri, {}, { isBinary: true });
      const rawImageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
      const imageTensor = this.imageToTensor(rawImageData);
      const predictions = await this.model.classify(imageTensor);
      this.setState({ predictions });
      console.log(predictions);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  selectImage = async () => {
    try {
      let response = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      });

      if (!response.canceled) {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        this.setState({ image: source });
        this.classifyImage();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  renderPrediction = (prediction) => {
    return (
      <Text key={prediction.className} style={styles.text}>
        {" "}
        {prediction.className}{" "}
      </Text>
    );
  };

  renderTranslation = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Translator
          from="en"
          to="fr"
          value={this.state.textToTranslate}
          onTranslated={(text) => this.setState({ translationResult: text })}
        />
        <TextInput
          value={this.state.textToTranslate}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ textToTranslate: text })}
        />
        <Text>{this.state.translationResult}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  // naviScreen = () => {
  //   const navigation = useNavigation();
  //   navigation.navigate('ScanScreen');
  // }

  render() {
    const { isTfReady, isModelReady, predictions, image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        {this.renderTranslation()}
        <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
          <View style={styles.loadingModelContainer}>
            {isTfReady && isModelReady ? (
              <Text style={styles.text}> APP IS READY FOR SCANNING! </Text>
            ) : (
              <ActivityIndicator size="small" />
            )}
          </View>
        </View>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.imageWrapper}
          onPress={isModelReady ? this.selectImage : undefined}
        >
          {image && <Image source={image} style={styles.imageContainer} />}

          {isModelReady && !image && (
            <Text style={styles.transparentText}>Tap to choose image</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <View style={styles.predictionWrapper}>
          {isModelReady && image && (
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              Predictions: {predictions ? "" : "Predicting..."}
            </Text>
          )}
          {isModelReady &&
            predictions &&
            predictions.map((p) => this.renderPrediction(p))}
        </View>

        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <Button style={styles.text} title="SAVE THIS IMAGE"></Button>
        </View>

        <Button
          title="LIVE Scan Now"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("ScanScreen")}
        ></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```